# c# Better Searching without lag

Tags: c#

I'm making a searching system, example below this works fine but its laggy. Is there a better way to search label in multiple panels?

```
private void search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control[] panels = flow.Controls.Find("panel", false);
    foreach(var panel in panels)
    {
        Control[] usernames = panel.Controls.Find("username", false);
        foreach(var username in usernames)
        {
            if (!username.Text.ToLower().Contains(search.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                panel.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                panel.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A HashSet would help here. Also, it looks like you can move `usernames` outside the loop.

Comment: well you could certainly move the searct.Text.ToLower out of the inner loop, but I cant see that would make much difference, how many controls are we talking about?

Comment: Panel visibility is changed multiple times, leaving it in the last state. Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: @pm100 there is over 100 panels.

Comment: `username.Text.ToLower().Contains(search.Text.ToLower())` - don't do this because you're causing excessive string-allocation. Use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Comment: I would not worry about excessive string allocation. It is like worrying about a few ants on an aircraft carrier. The best way to make this thing seem fast is to make sure that it updates only when the user is not typing for some time like half a second or so.

Answer (score 2):

- Use `Control.SuspendLayout` to avoid expensive control layout and painting operations when you change control visibility.
- Use a `StringComparison` that ignores-case instead of using `ToLower()` because that will cause excessive string-allocation (Strings in .NET are immutable).
- If your set of panels/controls doesn't change, consider building a `Dictionary<String,List<Control>>` once, so you can have `O(1)` access to controls rather than having to walk the control-tree.

Like so:

```
// This could be improved by using a `List<WeakReference<Control>>`.
private readonly Dictionary<String,List<Control>> allControlsByName = new Dictionary<String,List<Control>>();

private static void BuildControlDict( Control c, Dictionary<String,List<Control>> dict )
{
    if( dict.TryGetValue( c.Name, out List<Control> list )  )
    {
        list.Add( c );
    }
    else
    {
        dict[ c.Name ] = new List<Control>() { c };
    }

    foreach( Control child in c.Controls )
    {
        BuildControlDict( child, dict );
    } 
}


private void search_TextChanged( Object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    if( this.allControlsByName.Count == 0 )
    {
        BuildControlDict( this.flow, this.allControlsByName );
    } 

    if( !this.allControlsByName.TryGetValue( "username", out List<Control> userNameControls ) )
    {
        return;
    }

    //

    String searchTerm = this.search.Text;

    this.SuspendLayout();
    try
    {
        foreach( Control c in userNameControls )
        {
            Int32 idx = c.Text.IndexOf( searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase );
            Boolean isMatch = idx > -1;
            c.Visible = isMatch;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        this.ResumeLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can make use of the Parallel.ForEach to leverage the Parellel task libary to do concurrent operation. For example, you can perform the "username" search on each panel concurrently. The concurrent operation is manage by the framework Parallel libary.

This is how you would do it:

```
private void search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Control[] panels = flow.Controls.Find("panel", false);
   Parallel.ForEach(panels, panel=>{
        Control[] usernames = panel.Controls.Find("username", false);
        foreach (var username in usernames)
        {
            if (!username.Text.ToLower().Contains(search.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                panel.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                panel.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This won't work. It will crash at runtime because you cannot alter WinForms Control objects from other threads - only the single UI thread can alter controls.

Comment: Ah! i wasn't even thinking it was Winform. But yes, this code would only work with webforms.

Comment: It might not work with WebForms either if any of those Controls use `HttpContext.Current` in their property getters/setters because `HttpContext.Current` is stored using Thread-Local-Storage. That said, no-one should be using WebForms today.

Comment: Even if it did work, it would be the kind of solution such as "digging a canal by hand is slow: use more people to dig" instead of digging efficiently with machines.

Comment: @Dai, don't use HttpContext.Current if that is the case. Unfortunately, WebForms are still around and still supported by .Net framework. You would not start a project with WebForm nowaday, but there are still plenty of applications still running as webforms. Not my cup of tea with webforms, but it's still there and will be there for quite some time.